# The method execute() is undefined for the type InvoiceTemplateGet

Tags: android, android-asynctask, execution

I use AsyncTask to get result from API. I have several classes which works fine. I've created another AsyncTask class, but I get this error:

```
The method execute() is undefined for the type InvoiceTemplateGet
```

On this line:

```
InvoiceTemplateGet template = new InvoiceTemplateGet(PaymentMethodActivity.this, invoiceNumber);
template.execute();
```

There is the class InvoiceTemplateGet:

```
public class InvoiceTemplateGet {

    public InvoiceTemplateGet(Context context, String invoiceNumber){
        mContext = context;
        this.invoiceNumber = invoiceNumber;
        load_default_settings();
    }


    protected CustomAsyncTaskResult<String> doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        try{
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            String response = httpclient.execute(httpget,responseHandler);
            return new CustomAsyncTaskResult<String>(response);
        }catch (HttpResponseException e){
            return new CustomAsyncTaskResult<String>(new ApiException("Invoice", "Invoice was not found."));
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("Invoice Error", "Error:", e);
            return new CustomAsyncTaskResult<String>(new ApiException("Invoice", e.getMessage()));
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(CustomAsyncTaskResult<String> result) {
        ((PaymentMethodActivity)mContext).getResultFromTemplate(result);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

I have another class which is the same like this one, just url is different. It's executed on the same page like this one, on the same part of code. And it works, so why I'm still getting this error?

Comment: probably the other class is extending directly AsyncTask

Comment: Oh my god... Could you please write it like an answer?

Comment: looks like you copy-pasted the body of `InvoiceTemplateGet` class from somewhere, but you forgot to add `extends AsyncTask<String, Void, CustomAsyncTaskResult<String>>` to the class declaration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have another class which is the same like this one, just url is
>   different. It's executed on the same page like this one, on the same
>   part of code. And it works, so why I'm still getting this error?

your `InvoiceTemplateGet` hasn't a method called `execute()`. Looking at your code, it looks to me that you forgot to `extend AsyncTask`. You could also create your execute() method which instantiate the inner `AsyncTask` and call `instance.execute()`